# Scrolling in Usercontrol

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have developed one user control, which has ListBox. when we scrolling it is not happen for me can u tell me what would goes wrong in it?

I have following items,

1.Panorama Page
 In side controls:PanoramaItem I have created the instance of usecontrol

```
<controls:PanoramaItem Header ="Header">
    <Grid>
      <views:MyUserControlView DataContext="{Binding MyViewModel}" />
    </Grid>
</controls:PanoramaItem>
```

2.MyUserControlView

```
<UserControl x:Class="UI.Views.RecentFileView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:utility="clr-namespace:UI.CommandBehaviours" 

mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="364" d:DesignWidth="245">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="360">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListBox x:Name="RecentFilesListBox" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles}" 
                 utility:CommandService.Command="{Binding ToFileViewCommand}" utility:CommandService.CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=RecentFilesListBox}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="DataTemplateStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="ThumbnailImage" Source="{Binding Path=Thumbnail}" Height="43" Width="43" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,20,0"/>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="FileNameTextBlock" Text="{Binding  Path=FileName, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="FileserverNameTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=FileServerName}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

When I am Scrolling Its not working for me..

Comment: Can you provide your XAML markup? and some information about what is in this ListBox?

Comment: your question wasn't formatted to enable the smaple XAML to be displayed. I've reformatted it now.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean vertical scrolling, then the structure you've shown should work OK - although I'm a little bit concerned about where the `<ListBox>` is in your `<UserControl>`

Here are two things that should work:

**Option 1:**

```
<Panorama>
<PanoramaItem>
<MyUserControl>
</PanoramaItem>
</Panorama>
```

where MyUserControl is:

```
<UserControl>
<ScrollViewer>
<StackPanel>
... lots of <TextBlock>s
</StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

or...

**Option 2.**

```
<Panorama>
<PanoramaItem>
<MyUserControl>
</PanoramaItem>
</Panorama>
```

where MyUserControl is:

```
<UserControl>
<ListBox>
... lots of "items" possibly created inside a <DataTemplate>
<ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

If you want to put a list of items inside a ScrollViewer, then you might be better off using an ItemsControl instead.

Comment: Remove the Grid and ScrollViewer from the UserControl - the ListBox on  its own will provide the scrolling. i.e. the ListBox should be LayoutRoot for your UserControl

Answer (score 1):

The XAML you posted for your usercontrol isn't valid (it contains an extra `</StackPanel>`) and has lots more grids than you should need.

Try this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyProperty}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="{Binding MyImageSource}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock x:Name="Label" Text="{Binding MyLabel}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ReadOnlyTextBlock" Text="{Binding MyStatus}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="PaidTextBlock" Text="{Binding MyPurchase}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" Foreground="Blue"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: @dinesh can you post a complete example. I'm having issues trying to recreate your problem.

Comment: @dinesh that's very different to the xaml you had previously but still not a COMPLETE example.